# Transparent material from 2.79 is solid in 2.82

Tags: materials, transparency

I just switched from 2.79 to 2.82 and I face 2 problems. In 2.79 I could simply select a material to be transparent and set the parameters (alpha etc.). I do not find these options in the 2.82 materials menu. Are they gone? Even worse: When I import old files from 2.79 formerly transparent materials are now solid. Do I have to switch back to the old version? I only need simple transparency, no imported images or more complex stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Cycles* still works the same.
But in *Eevee*, you need to enable transparency per material.

Set *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Blend* in the material settings.

[image]